Get Xaxis on top in Google Gantt chart
need to move to top  I am using this code this is a dummy data from google my code is much bigger and data comes from mysql server but the structure is similar
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
      return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
      data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

      data.addRows([
        ['Research', 'Find sources', null,
         new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
        ['Write', 'Write paper', 'write',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 9), daysToMilliseconds(3), 25, 'Research,Outline'],
        ['Cite', 'Create bibliography', 'write',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 7), daysToMilliseconds(1), 20, 'Research'],
        ['Complete', 'Hand in paper', 'complete',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 10), daysToMilliseconds(1), 0, 'Cite,Write'],
        ['Outline', 'Outline paper', 'write',
         null, new Date(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research']
      ]);

      var options = {
        height: 275
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>


I haven't found any thing in documentation but I tried manupulating dom but the chart does not rerender
 xtextElements.each(function() {
                        // Move each text element before the first <rect> element within the same parent
                        $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings('rect').first());
                        
                    });

